# How to convert a SparseArray to ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

I know this is possible:

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
...
List<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>(map.values());
```

But according to android `SparseArray<Object>` is more efficient, hence, I am wondering if it is possible to convert a `SparseArray` to `Arraylist`.

Much appreciate any input.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This will get just the values, ignoring gaps between indices (as your existing Map solution does):

```
public static <C> List<C> asList(SparseArray<C> sparseArray) {
    if (sparseArray == null) return null;
    List<C> arrayList = new ArrayList<C>(sparseArray.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); i++)
        arrayList.add(sparseArray.valueAt(i));
    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems like a tedious way of doing it? do you know of another way? like the the `List<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>(map.values());` for Map, for example?

Comment: This is the only way to do it. Write it in a method once, then forget about how tedious it is!

Comment: How much overhead is the HashMap?  Seems like it might be better to use HashMap in a case where you need easy access to the arraylist of values even when using Integers as the key, rather than creating a loop that iterates to generate that arraylist.  Am I overthinking it?  Need to go test both I guess.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy HashMap will take unnecessary space in memory to do the same thing. So, considering we are talking about a mobile application, it's always important to take care of memory and give preference do SparseArrays.

Comment: I was wondering if the HashMap takes up so much extra space in memory that it is more than the SparseArray + the new ArrayList to iterate over the values.

Comment: How could this answer given as correct? You can add values to an SparseArray with a specific int value; so, lets simplify this.
I add a value with int key = 100.
sparseArray.size() will return 1.
Then, you won't obtain stored value on position 100.

Comment: @Kensei, yes, the first line of the answer says as much. The OP just wants the values and this does that. It never claims to maintain key/index positions.

Answer (score 2):

[ArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArrayMap.html) looks like a better choice, which is available since API 19.

Comment: How? If I have to make a List out of an SparseArray I don't see any advantage in using another class in between.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version:

```
   fun <T> SparseArray<T>.values(): List<T> {
        val list = ArrayList<T>()
        forEach { _, value ->
            list.add(value)
        }
    return  list.toList()
```

Comment: This will not work for `android.util.SparseArray`, there is no `forEach` method.

Comment: What is the purpose of toList() here?